# About using Rewriterule .? & {REQUEST_URI} variable to redirect all old domain to new

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

Is it correct to use

```
 RewriteRule .? http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

to redirect all pages from old domain to new domain (including 404)?

I have it in one of my htaccess. It works but i don't know if it is right.

Answer (score 1):

OP's solution using REQUEST_URI is good and preferable to using the often seen ^(.*)$ and $1.

Reasons:

- REQUEST_URI correctly preserves paths with missing trailing slashes (which $1 does not do). So `olddomain.com/path` will redirect to `newdomain/path` perfectly. With $1 only `olddomain.com/path/` will redirect to `newdomain/path/` but a path segment with missing trailing slash will be removed.
- REQUEST_URI correctly preserves any query string, which would require an additional QSA flag with the $1 solution.

There is only one little improvement that I propose: 
Make the matching pattern even shorter. A single caret will suffice to match anything:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but it's not the way I'd do it. The `.?` means "the URL contains 0 or 1 of anything", which is a slightly odd way of matching everything.

The way I would approach it is to "capture" the URL matched and use that in the target.

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Here, `.*` means "match anything", the `^` and `$` represent the beginning and end of the URL, making it "match everything", and the `$1` refers to whatever was matched in the first (and in this case only) set of brackets.

Seems more complicated, now I look at it, but is more similar to the rules you would need if you wanted to match only some URLs, or construct the target differently.

Comment: While this method also works the method in the OP is more efficient, since 1) it doesn't have to match the whole URL, it just checks there was anything requested and 2) doesn't need to create a backreference to capture something Apache already knows from the get-go (the value of `%{REQUEST_URI}`)

Comment: @ScallioXTX Good point. I guess I was thinking from a human-efficiency point of view (readability and maintainability): keeping everything in a familiar form that can be easily modified for different situations (such as redirecting a sub-directory to its own domain).